# How can I create, modify and push my changes to Azure DevOps repository programmatically

Tags: python, c#, azure, go

I am writing small utility to automate a repetitive task in which, I wanted to create branch of a repository in Azure DevOps, make some changes and push the changes programmatically.

I tried googling for the library/solution but could not find any.

Does anyone help me with library in c#/golang/python using which I can achieve the same?

I tried searching for library/solution over google and did not find any good solution.

Comment: Don't google for Azure DevOps, just google for "git", and script the command line tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of their [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).
Essentially you will be working with git via Azure DevOps Services.